# OnItemClick under Fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-listview, fragment, android-adapter

I don't know why but my onItemClickmethod is not even calling. Well, it was working fine before adding the button(add button see adapter) on each row.

Please help me to find the bug,thanks

```
@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Init();

    //People list click
    chatPeoples.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Log.i("click", "Clicking ");
            PeopleObject p = peopleObjList.get(position);
            String chattingToName = p.getPersonName();
            String chattingToDeviceID = p.getRegId();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChatActivityNew.class);
            intent.putExtra("chattingFrom",MyUsername);
            intent.putExtra("chattingToName", chattingToName);
            intent.putExtra("chattingToDeviceID", chattingToDeviceID);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (eSearch.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                eSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });


   // setMyUsername();
    //getPeopleList();
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity context;
private ArrayList<PeopleObject> chatPeoplesUsername;

public ChatAdapter(Activity cont, ArrayList<PeopleObject> cUsername ){
    this.context = cont;
    this.chatPeoplesUsername = cUsername;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView txUsername;
    protected Button addFriend;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chatPeoplesUsername.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chat_people_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.txUsername = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.person_username);
        viewHolder.addFriend = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_friend);


        viewHolder.addFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "hm ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (chatPeoplesUsername != null) {
        PeopleObject h = chatPeoplesUsername.get(position);
        viewHolder.txUsername.setText(h.getPersonName());

    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: show your xml files  of your `chat_people_row.xml`

Comment: post your  chat_people_row.xml

Comment: post xml and code with launcher actiivty

Comment: I got the problem was that I didn't know that I have to add android:focusable="false" on the row layout.Thanks a lot to shreyash. However, I don't understand why am I receiving negative votes. Just sory to shreyash that I am unable to give vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added button on you every listItem right?

then just put this line in you button's xml file and all will work fine

```
android:focusable="false"
```

so button's xml should be like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Reason behind this is button will take focus of all things when you click on listItem so there method will be called not list's click.

Answer (score 1):

Move your click listner to `getView()` method

```
  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("click", "Clicking ");
            //remaining code            
        }
    });
```

Comment: You mean out of  `if (convertView == null)` condition right ?

Comment: Thanks but I need to keep the listener into my fragment class

Answer (score 0):

You can not use clickable components like button and OnClickListener together.in such case your OnClickListener wont get called.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you didn't get my question and it is working fine now